# Twilml recived emty post request

Tags: php, api, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

i am using following function to make a voice call using twillio

```
function callCustomer(phoneNumber) {
    updateCallStatus("Calling " + phoneNumber + "...", 2);

    var params = {
        "phoneNumber": phoneNumber
    };
    Twilio.Device.connect(params);
}
```

in which phoneNumber is passed properly.but in php file which is inside twilML recives blank phoneNumber

my twilMl File is as follow

```
<?php
    header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
    include_once __DIR__ . '/includes/connect.inc.php';
?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId='<?= TWILIO_ACCOUNT_NUMBER ?>'><?= trim($_POST['phoneNumber']) ?></Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: Is your TwiML app set to make a `GET` or `POST` request to your PHP application? Are you able to inspect the parameters in the webhook request?

Comment: currently it set to `POST`

Comment: Are you able to inspect the parameters in the webhook request?

Comment: its solved by changing the request to `get` but idk why POST with POST method its not working

Comment: That is odd. `POST` should work, in fact I always use `POST` for my Twilio webhooks. Does `$_REQUEST` work instead of `$_POST` maybe?

Comment: When i set `POST` in Twiml Application that is not work for my. but when i change to `$_GET` it works fine

Comment: All I can suggest is that you log the incoming request and see what the `POST` body is and why you might not be seeing the parameters in your code.